# Why is only the first record being returned from this PHP array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to return four records from my MySQL database but only the first record is being returned. I've searched but I'm unsure why this is. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
    <?php
session_start();
function displayImage($username){
    $imageDate  = $_POST['imageDate'];
    $result = mysql_query("
        SELECT
            imageName
        FROM
            images AS i
        INNER JOIN
            users AS u ON i.userID = u.UserID
        WHERE
            u.username = '$username'
        AND
            i.imageDate = '$imageDate'

    ") or die(mysql_error());

    //return a message to the users explaining ......
        if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
            // this does nowt yet!!!
            $output = "Nothing selected yet.";
        }
        else {
        //This is a while loop to store the SQL results into ......
        $row = array(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
        foreach ($row as $picName) {
        $cam = $_POST['cam'];
        $fullPath = $username . "/" . $cam . "/" . $picName['imageName'];
        // $output = //this works fine
                reset($images);
            }
        }
        var_dump($row);
        echo "<br />";
        return $output;
    }
?>
```

Comment: "//This is a while loop to store the SQL results into ......" - No it's not. You want something like `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) { ... }` but while you are at it, please consider switching to PDO.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in here, by the way - you need to escape anything coming in from the POST array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others here have said, you need to use a while loop for this, I've tidied the code up a tiny bit and added a couple of other things for you to consider.

The actual reason for this is that when you use mysql_fetch_assoc it brings back one result resource and removes it from resources it has left to return. So if you just try and store it in an array, you get the first one in the array, and nothing else. When you use a while loop it works by basically saying "if mysql_fetch_assoc has something to give, then do the code inside the loop".

```
<?php

session_start();

function displayImage($username) {
    // Also, as others have said, check out PDO, or MySQLi, as they
    // both provide a better interface with MySQL an have better
    // security features.
    $username  = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $imageDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imageDate']);

    $result = mysql_query("
        SELECT
            imageName
        FROM
            images AS i
        INNER JOIN
            users AS u ON i.userID = u.UserID
        WHERE
            u.username = '$username'
    AND 
            i.imageDate = '$imageDate'
    ") or die(mysql_error());

    //return a message to the users explaining
    if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        // this does nowt yet!!!
        $output = "Nothing selected yet.";
    } else {
        $cam = $_POST['cam'];

        $images = array(); // This is part of the "you could do something 
                           // like" further down.
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $fullPath = $username . '/' . $cam . '/' . $row['imageName'];
            // $output = //this works fine
            var_dump($row);
            echo "<br />";

            // Or you could do something like:

            $images[] = $username . '/' . $cam . '/' . $row['imageName'];

            // Then outside of this while loop you'd have all of your image 
            // paths stored in this $images array. 
            // 
            // It depends on how you want to handle outputting them.
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

The comments in the code go through my main points.

I also moved that $cam = $_POST['cam'] from inside of the loop, to outside of it, as it doesn't need to go in the loop because it's value will always be the same, regardless of which loop item you're going over.

Comment: fixed my code, thank you to all for help. I see all the records now in the var-dump. I can't mark anyone up yet as my reputation is too low, thanks again guys, I spent pretty much all of yesterday trying to get my head around this.

Comment: @GrahamSnowdon You can mark the correct answer at your reputation

Answer (score 6):

You should use loop to fetch result:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $cam = $_POST['cam'];
        $fullPath = $username . "/" . $cam . "/" . $row['imageName'];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to use mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_array is this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // This is an example...
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still need an explanation:

**1. Why you got only one record??**

When you declare:

```
$row=array(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

This means that you get one record from the database, the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` method was run only once, so your method calls 1 row from the database table.

**2. How to get this to work?**

Like you have seen in the example given by others, use a `while` loop instead.

**2.1 How does the loop work?**

When you call:

```
     while (<some command1 equates to true or false>) {<some command2>}
```

At first they run somecommand1. If it returns true, do some command2. After command2 has finished, run somecommand1 again. If it still true, do somecommand2 and so on... A nice example is the command you're using.

```
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
         echo $row['fieldname1'];
         echo $row['fieldname2'];
     }
```

In this loop $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) is Somecommand1 as explained. This function returns a resource which equates to true if there is another row returned from the database. After one run through of the code within the while loop it skips onto the next row. Then it re-runs the `mysql_fetch_assoc` function. If there is still some record in the table that matches the query, this function will still do whatever is in your while loop.

If you need more examples, take a look at w3schools.com. I started PHP from there.

Comment: Are you implying that the name of a variable is linked to its content? If a row is a vertical line, what is a column?

Comment: a horizontal line of course. (vertical is left to tight and horizontal is up to down, right?) You can see in microsoft word when making a table , a nice example

Comment: @n.1 $row is widely use for mysql , so I assumed he must learn the example somewhere. And di you the one voted my answer down? Can I have a reason please

Comment: You said *This means that you get one record from the database. Why? The name you use for the variable is $row* then explain later why there is only one row. I think this can be misunderstood by beginners, the name of the variable can't be used to guess its content.

Comment: *vertical is left to tight and horizontal is up to down, right?* No. When you fall, you move horizontally from top to bottom?

Comment: My country dictionary said it that way , sorry It's horizontal. If you think you are cool, edit my post. Or explain the way **not to be misunderstood by new user**  By the way, would you name columm as $row? I just guess it because If you did look for most of the tutorial , they use $row for mysql connection tutorial. Would you name an int that use for counting as "constantnumber"? That's basic of programming. If you see my explaination , at least **THINK**. I used this case to easily explain to users that it does say it is a row. Why be rude?

Comment: I think it's right to call it a row since you iterate over rows of the table. [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) returns a row.

Comment: @n.1 Could you tell me what to edit and why? I am getting confused

Comment: I've edited your answer. I removed the part about horizontal and vertical lines, calling it a row is easier and still perfectly valid.